# Load_history does not show failed loads when running copy using JDBC 3.9.2 but shows up when running using the Snowflake console

Tags: load, history, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

we are trying to copy some files into snowflake using JDBC 3.9.2. The copy failed due to a column mismatch. 
when checking the Load_history table to see the error, it did not show up any rows in load_history view.
When this same copy was run from the snowflake console we were able to see all the files and the error associated with the failure with the status as 'LOAD_FAILED'.

Why is it that load_history is not showing up failed status when running from a client using JDBC3.9.2 and showing up when the same copy command failed is executed from the snowflake console.Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

In JDBC try this:

SnowflakeStatement.getQueryID()

Then use that id to quesry the Load_history table.

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/account-usage/load_history.html

This will give you the last id.
 SELECT LAST_QUERY_ID();

Is this what you were looking for?